# Do primes of the form $4k+1$ ever lead the greatest prime factor race?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory, conjectures

Analogous to Chebyshev's race between primes, I examined the race between primes in the [greatest prime factors, GPF](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestPrimeFactor.html), of natural numbers. Similar to the regular prime race, in the GPF race, the proportion of prime of both forms is roughly $50\%$ each. However, unlike the regular prime race where the race is equal ([A038691](http://oeis.org/A038691)) or changes lead between primes of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$ ([A096628](http://oeis.org/A096628)) in the GPF race, $4k+3$ dominates. For $n \le 3 \times 10^{10}$, there are $14970975209$ numbers the GPF is of the form $4k+1$ and $15029024755$ numbers where $GPF$ is of the form $4k+3$ and up till this point, there is not a single instance where primes of the form $4k+1$ equal or take the lead in the race.

Let $f_1(n)$ and $f_3(n)$ be the number of natural numbers $\le n$ in which the GPF is of the form $4k+1$ and $4k+3$ respectively. The difference between the number of GPFs on these two forms appeared to increase in a very orderly manner as shown in the graph below.

[image: Graph of f3 - f1]

**Question 1**: Does the GPF race ever become equal or change the lead i.e. is there an $n$ such that $f_1(n) = f_3(n)$?

Clearly, the graph is sub-linear. I applied different curve fitting models to this data to have an idea of the growth rate. The best fit was given by

$$
f_3(n) - f_1(n) \approx an^b
$$

where $a \approx 0.1785$ and $b \approx 0.8122$. This experimental model has a very high $R^2 = 0.9999958$. If this is close to the true growth rate then, prime of the form $4k+1$ will always lag behind in the GPF race.

**Question 2**: What is the true growth rate of $f_3(n) - f_1(n)$?

Check out the interesting comments by Greg Martin ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423531/do-prime-of-the-form-4k1-ever-lead-the-greatest-prime-factor-race#comment9257674_4423531) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423531/do-prime-of-the-form-4k1-ever-lead-the-greatest-prime-factor-race#comment9257701_4423531)) and Eric Naslund ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423531/do-prime-of-the-form-4k1-ever-lead-the-greatest-prime-factor-race#comment9338686_4423531) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423531/do-prime-of-the-form-4k1-ever-lead-the-greatest-prime-factor-race#comment9339575_4423531) [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423531/do-prime-of-the-form-4k1-ever-lead-the-greatest-prime-factor-race#comment9339884_4423531)) in the linked question in MSE.

**Note**: Was [posted on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423531/do-prime-of-the-form-4k1-ever-lead-the-greatest-prime-factor-race) but was unanswered. Hence posting in MO.

Comment: Great question, but I suspect that the data is misleading. It's probably true that $1 \pmod{4}$ will win 50% of the time, but that $3 \pmod{4}$ has a lead for small values, which is what you are seeing right now.